# In my JFrame project, my methods are being completed twice. What is causing this?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

First class

```
package com.mudd.render;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.mudd.game.Game;




public class render {
    int width = 500;
    int height = 600;

    Game g = new Game();

    public void show(){
        JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame("..");


        gameWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        //gameWindow.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage());


        gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        gameWindow.pack();

        gameWindow.add(g);

        gameWindow.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        render game = new render();

        game.show();

    }

}
```

Second class

```
package com.mudd.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {


    public void paint(Graphics g){

         g.fillOval(10, 10, 500, 500);

         System.out.println("Test");
        }

}
```

What is causing my Test print statement to be printed twice? If I add other priintlns it will also print them both out. I've been learning Java from Head First Java and I've done other small command line projects but nothing like this has ever happened to me.

Comment: Did you bother looking at the javadocs for `paint`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)  It is called by Swing, so if Swing wants to call it twice, then so be it.

Answer (score 2):

Swing graphics are passive -- you don't call the painting methods directly yourself, but rather the JVM calls them. They are sometimes possibly called at your *suggestion* such as when you call `repaint()` but even this is never a guarantee, and they are sometimes possibly called at the suggestion of the platform, such as when it determines that your application has "dirty" pixels that need cleaning. So you have to plan for this -- the painting method should contain no code that changes the state of the object nor should it contain business logic code. Instead it should have code for painting and nothing more.

For more details on this, please see:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Side recommendations:

- Override the JPanel's paintComponent method, not its paint method
- Use the `@Override` annotation for any method override
- Don't forget to call the super's method in your override.